# DTMF tone in RecognitionListener.onReadyForSpeech() mistaken for speech

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

The Google Voice Search comes with a significant delay from the moment you call it via startActivityForResult() until its dialog box is displayed, ready to take your speech.

This requires the user to always look at the screen, waiting for the dialog box to be displayed, before speaking.

So I was thinking of generating an audible signal instead of the dialog box by implementing RecognitionListener and sounding a DTMF tone in onReadyForSpeech() as in the following snippet:

```
  @Override
  public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    Log.d(LCTAG, "Called when the endpointer is ready for the user to start speaking.");
    mToneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Log.e(LCTAG, "InterruptedException while in Thread.sleep(50).");        
      e.printStackTrace();
    } // SystemClock.sleep(50);
    mToneGenerator.stopTone();
  }
```

The tone sounds beautifully but... it is also "heard" by the microphone, arriving to the voice recognition service and *always* generating a recognition error **ERROR_NO_MATCH**.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a random idea, and it may very well not work.

Can you try disabling the microphone (maybe via `AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute`) while the tone is played?

Comment: Great idea (+1). I quickly implemented it, but it produced the same ERROR_NO_MATCH recognition error. Either the mute is for a different input stream or the beep is somehow funneled through a "local loop" to the SR service.

Comment: Sigh, sorry to hear that. You could try playing with other settings (input stream volume, maybe), but I have the feeling that the voice recognition is overriding (or ignoring) the settings.

Comment: I haven't been able to solve the problem yet, but your answer is the best so far, so I am accepting it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but if I trip over a solution by chance, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code that's working for me, put into the onReadyForSpeech() callback of the RecognitionListener.

```
private void playSpeechReadyTone(){
    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(JarvisService.this, R.raw.doublebeep);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.start();    
}
```

Comment: It is my understanding that `setMicrophoneMute()` is [totally unreliable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7105567/679180). IOW, it may be working on some phones, but it is not guaranteed to work on all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there isn't an easy&clean way to do that. As srf appointed, you shouldn't rely on AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(boolean), so, AFAIK, the possibles are:

1. Play an audio file before call SpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent):

   ```
   final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(JarvisService.this, R.raw.doublebeep);
   mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
           player.release();
           // Safety start Speech Recognizer
           mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(getSpeechRecognizerIntent());
       }
   });
   mediaPlayer.start();
   ```

However, this solution has a problem... If may receive an RecognitionListener.onError(int error) before RecognitionListener.onReadyForSpeech being called and, in that case, you are still playing a beep sound every time (this will happen, for example, if you are not connected to the Internet and Speech Recognition is configured to work online)!
Besides, you should manage the case of cancelling the speech recognition process during audio (doublebeep) play.

1. Play the audio in the onReadyForSpeech callback (read original question) but use RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS with an appropriate value. In my case, my beep sound is really short (1 second max) and I set RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS to 4/5 seconds.

Also note that, as Google doc says:

> Note also that certain values may cause undesired or unexpected results - use judiciously! Additionally, depending on the recognizer implementation, these values may have no effect.