# Where do I find AudioHardware.cpp for the Nexus One?

Tags: android, nexus-one, cyanogenmod

Googling for [Nexus One AudioHardware.cpp](http://www.google.com/#q=Nexus+One+AudioHardware.cpp&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=hEtNToXWOMvngQfv1fmIBw&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=82f9f46bc5e7e168&biw=1010&bih=746) yields lots of results but none brings the actual source file as can easily found for other phones (e.g. [Vogue](http://vogue-android.googlecode.com/hg/AudioHardware.cpp) or [msm7k](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/hardware/msm7k.git;a=blob;f=libaudio-qsd8k/AudioHardware.cpp;h=7656ffaba02237aa6600b51cf3da081513e64f43;hb=da9d5ab10524c32d7949363a10fde1bec5fdf9fa#l1008)).

If possible, I would like to find both the stock (Google's official) version and the CyanogenMod one.

Pointers to exact locations would be very much appreciated.