# Can we access the Microphone driver of my android phone

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, linux-kernel, java-native-interface

Can we access the Microphone driver of my android phone using Android NDK if so then how can I?

Can I set the driver disabled for some time?

Can I detect application name of my phone which is using my phone microphone?

As per Android Multimedia framework the MediaServer is responsible for opening the device and the Java based audio applications connect it as a client. The data transfer happens on the Binder. May because of this there is only one process seen which opens the audio device. Now I want to know how to get information from MediaServer? Anyone knows this or any other idea to find which application is using my phone microphone,i can't use the root permission.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874881/how-does-setmicrophonemute-work

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. :-)
(even using NDK)

Specific hacks **might** exist for certain devices.
But they would definitely interfere with the proper operation of Android framework.