# Turn off microphone in android

Tags: android, microphone

I want to turn off or disable the microphone during a call.
I searched, but I got almost nothing. Some people say it is not possible in android.

How do I turn off the microphone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does setMicrophoneMute() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874881/how-does-setmicrophonemute-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can't completely disable the microphone. But you can play around the **audio manager**, to mute it etc...

[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode%28int%29)